# Cap deploy doesn't create share/log folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

When I run my cap deploy, it complains that it can't access the log file:

> Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that
>   /var/superduperapp/releases/20120329011558/log/production.log exists
>   and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the
>   output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

It seems that I have to manually create a log folder.  Is there a way to do this with Capistrano so whoever is deploying it doesn't have to remember to create the folder each time they do a new deploy?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These folders should be created by capistrano when you run `cap deploy:setup`, have you ran it? To check if everything is fine you can run `cap deploy:check` before it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom task to create this directory and launch it as the first task:

```
task :create_log_share do
  run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/log"
end
before 'deploy:update', :create_log_share
```

This directory does not need to be created each the time when you deploy. Once is enough. The shared directory never changes.

Comment: Thanks @shingara, that worked for me. Now I just have to figure out why my Unicorn server doesn't show anything in the terminal besides: `SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized'. Hmm..